# generating a full combination of values from multiple lists in python?

Tags: python, generator

I would like to generate a full-matrix of value combinations from multiple lists.  But I don't always know how many lists will be provided, and each one can have a different length.  I was able to get the answer by abusing itertools.product(), but I think it's overkill.  Is there a more pythonic way?

```
import itertools

listoflists = [
   ["happy","sad"],
   ["car","bike","truck"],
   ["true","false"],
   [3,6,34,8,31]]

def comboGenerator(lol):

  # create a uniform N-dimensional struct, big enough to hold longest dimension
  longest = max(map(lambda x: len(x),lol))
  superstruct = itertools.product(range(longest), repeat=len(lol))

  # visit each cell in the struct, ignore the empty ones
  for a in superstruct:
    combo = []
    try:
      for index in range(len(lol)):
        combo.append(lol[index][a[index]])
      yield (combo)
    except IndexError:  #this was an empty cell; try again
      pass

for x in comboGenerator(listoflists):
  print (x)
```

Comment: If your code is working, consider asking this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = list(itertools.product(*listoflists))
```

if you want the element type of `result` list be a `list`, then convert it by:

```
result = [list(item) for item in result]
```

Comment: It always hurts when you spend all that time on confusing code and then you find out you can do the same thing in two lines.